# Java - Possible to Remove all Characters except '.' and numbers for double/floats?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

There is a small problem I am trying to solve, it is a part of code that basically checks versions against versions on other machines via version files. It looks at the names of these files, and strips all characters currently.

At first, I tried:

```
private String getLatestVerFile( List<String> verFiles ) {

    String latestVerFile = null;
    long lastMod = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    for (String file : verFiles ) {

        if ( Long.parseLong( file.replaceAll( "[^0-9]", "" ) ) > lastMod ) {
            latestVerFile = file;
            lastMod = Long.parseLong( file.replaceAll( "[^0-9]", "" ) );
        }
    }

    return latestVerFile;       
}
```

The problem here is given multiple version files, it is meant to return the latest one, and it won't in some cases:

```
ex:
R9.10 = 910
R9.26_P1 = 9261
R9.01 = 901
R10.1 = 101
```

In this case, R10.1 would be the latest version.

Personally I would like for them to adopt a more standard and straightforward release numbering scheme, but that's out of my control.

My idea was to try handling this as a double. I thought you could use [^0-9.] per some Google searching, as seen below.

```
private String getLatestVerFile( List<String> verFiles ) {

    String latestVerFile = null;
    double lastMod = Double.MIN_VALUE;

    for (String file : verFiles ) {

        if ( Double.parseDouble( file.replaceAll( "[^0-9.]", "" ) ) > lastMod ) {
            latestVerFile = file;
            lastMod = Double.parseDouble( file.replaceAll( "[^0-9.]", "" ) );
        }
    }

    return latestVerFile;       
}
```

That said, it doesn't work. I think what may be throwing this off is the fact the filename is R9.10.ver, for example, and it's possibly coming out as "9.10." and trying to make that a double. A coworker said to use R(\d+.\d+)(_P\d+1).ver, but I don't know where to begin with all of that, or how it would know what to filter out of the string.

The goal is to get this:

```
ex:
R9.10 = 9.10
R9.20_P1 = 9.201
R10.11 = 10.11
R10.20_P1 = 10.201
```

But I'm especially stuck on how I can get this done. Advice? I guess part of my problem is I'm honestly not understanding regular expressions all that well, and how to choose what parts to ignore of the pattern.

Comment: try escaping the period to \\.

Comment: @RedDeckWins: It's fine to have an unescaped `.` in a character class.

Comment: Yeah the problem with this was it gets the "." in the file extension as well. Every file has .ver at the end.

Answer (score 4):

I would say forget using Double (release numbers are **not** floating point numbers *at all*) and create your own comparable class called ReleaseNumber:

```
//details left out for brevity
public class ReleaseNumber implements Comparable<ReleaseNumber> {
    private final int majorVersion;
    private final int minorVersion;
}
```

You could then use a regular expression to get the fields of release number from each String:

```
//...
List<String> fileNames /* = ... */;

String latestVersionFileName = Collections.max(fileNames, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String file1, String file2) {
        return getReleaseNumberFromFileName(file1)
                 .compareTo(getReleaseNumberFromFileName(file2));
    }
}

//...

Pattern releaseNumberPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)");

public ReleaseNumber getReleaseNumberFromFileName(String fileName) {
    Matcher releaseNumberMatcher = releaseNumberPattern.matcher(fileName);
    if (releaseNumberMatcher.find()) {
        int majorVersion = Integer.parseInt(releaseNumberMatcher.group(1));
        int minorVersion = Integer.parseInt(releaseNumberMatcher.group(2));
        ReleaseNumber version = new ReleaseNumber(majorVersion, minorVersion);
        return version;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

In this case, we just use a simple regular expression `\d+\.\d+` which means "one or more decimal digits, followed by a dot, followed by one or more decimal digits" and we search the file contents for the first occurrence of that pattern.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will give this a try. If anyone has any other ideas feel free, I'll keep watching.

Comment: One interesting thing about this, is in the regex:

    Pattern releaseNumberPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)");

Is that going to get numbers following Patch numbers as well? A sample release pattern would look like:
R9.1
R9.20 (sometimes, for whatever reason, they trail them with zeroes)
R9.55
R9.55 P1
No future releases after 9.55 P1, just patched upon after 9.55.

Guess we could also have majorRevision, minorRevision, and patchRevision? That sounds like I may have made it too complicated though, as the patch revision number could simply be appended to the minorRevision

Comment: @Andrew: If you had a string like "R9.1 R9.20" it would extract a major version of 9 and a minor version of 1 (not 1920).  That's because it does not allow the string of decimal digits to be interrupted by other characters.  If you wanted to get more than one release number from the file name, you could turn the `if` block into a `while` loop instead (`while (releaseNumberMatcher.find()) { ...`).  It seems like you need to do some requirements gathering to find out exactly *what* a version's format is, and how to compare them.  Only then can you write the code, which can't have "fuzzy" reqs.

Comment: Totally agree, I feel our requirements are too loose on the version numbers, but another team owns those files :( Such is life.

I figured I should share how I ultimately fixed the issue. I took the same code as above when I simply did replaceAll(), but also formatted the string prior to chop off the file extension through the use of the .substring() method, thus not having the issue of multiple periods. I did try some of what you provided above, but I just couldn't get it to work within the context of the code. Thank you for helping though, I hope this example is useful to everyone.